# Customize Job Id in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

In spring batch,the job id gets generated internally.Is there any way I can have my own value set in job id?
Our client will send an order id as part of request.So,I want that order id to be set as the Job id by the jobLauncher.

Any way to achieve it?

Can we set in org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder

Comment: No that's not possible because this is used internally to store it in the database. Why don't you pass the order id as Jobparameter?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli in that case how can i access it ..how will i related by h job with this  order id later if i pass it as part of JobParametersBuilder

Comment: You can use the class JobExplorer to find this JobExecutions and there you can check for the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In spring batch,the job id gets generated internally.Is there any way I can have my own value set in job id?

The closest you can get for this a is a custom `DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer` for job instance IDs, which you can provide through `JobRepositoryFactoryBean#setIncrementerFactory`. This allows you to customize how the sequence of IDs is generated.

However, this API is for incrementing values in a sequence, so I'm not sure you can use it to assign random IDs. Otherwise, it would be an incorrect usage of the API. That said, I would pass the order ID as a job parameter (as recommended in comments by Simon Martinelli) and look for the job ID with the `JobExplorer` to find the association between the order ID and the corresponding job ID.